# How can I validate an XSLT template's logic against an XML schema?

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

An XSLT transform makes implicit assumptions about the structure of the XML that it is transforming.  For example, the following:

```
<xsl:variable name="b"><xsl:value-of select="A/B"/></xsl:variable>
```

Assumes that the XML node "B" sits directly underneath "A", such as:

```
<A>
  <B>Hello</B>
<\A>
```

If the XML format has changed, and becomes:

```
<A>
  <AA>
    <B>Hello</B>
  </AA>
<\A>
```

The XSLT will now fail to find node B, and will assume that the node hadn't been specified in this case (which would be a valid option).

I had assumed that it would be possible to specify the XML schema that the XSLT is attempting to transform, and if the XSLT ever referenced a node that the schema didn't recognise, a validation error would be raised.  However, I can't seem to find this implementation (https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-schemaxslt/index.html appears to mention only validating the input XML and the generated XML - not the XSLT itself).

*[Although an approach might be to create a XML schema of what the XSLT is expecting, and then compare the input XML against it, I have 100's of XSLTs at different versions, so this is impractical.  It is simple, however, to create an XSD of the input and ask the XSLT if it is OK with that.]*

Comment: That snippet you have shown is not even a template so I am not sure what your question with "validate an XSLT template's logic" refers to. What do you expect to happen with a stylesheet that creates a temporary nodes and processes them further? The path `A/B` does not even indicate any schema type. As for your general idea, I think Saxon EE with the right tool supports that, see http://www.stylusstudio.com/schema-aware.html for an example explanation.

Comment: Thanks, @MartinHonnen - that link is useful, but because of the 100's of XSLT sheets that I have, I don't what to re-write them all (unless I can do it programmatically, and even then...).  The example I gave was just an example snippet, so not a complete XSLT document,

Comment: @MartinHonnen - can I just check my interpretation?  Does it just require the "match" to be made dependent on the template, and after that the validation is done on anything below it?  In other words, only two modifications are required: to reference the template, and to use "match="schema-element(result)"" for the initial match statement?

Comment: Those warnings explained in that article are, as far as I understand, a feature of Saxon EE. I think it is clear that such warnings are only possible if a schema component is referenced, I am afraid I am not familiar enough with that feature of Saxon and certainly in no way with its implementation to help you further on that. I am sure @MichaelKay can and will tell you more if you ask in the Saxonica forum or tag your question with Saxon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what schema-aware processing in XSLT 2.0/3.0 is designed to achieve.

In the match pattern of a template rule, you have to declare that you are only going to use it to process schema-valid elements:

```
<xsl:template match="schema-element(invoice)">
 ...
</xsl:template>
```

or in XSLT 3.0 you can declare that all the template rules in a mode are designed to handle schema-valid input:

```
<xsl:mode typed="strict"/>
```

and then if you use a path that can't exist according to the schema, for example

```
<xsl:template match="schema-element(invoice)">
 <xsl:apply-templates select="customer-detials"/>
</xsl:template>
```

the XSLT processor will tell you about it. You have to tell the XSLT processor where to find the schema using an `<xsl:import-schema>` declaration.

Schema-awareness is a vastly underused feature of the language. It takes a bit of effort up-front to take advantage of it, and it can sometimes be a bit of a hassle with "false positive" error messages, but once you get the hang of it, it can catch a great number of simple user errors that would otherwise take hours to debug. In some cases schema-awareness can also aid performance, by reducing the amount of the source document that needs to be searched, and by avoiding repeated datatype conversions -- but better static error checking is the main benefit.

Comment: Thanks, @MichaelKay.  It certainly seems the proper way of doing it - rather than relying on the Hail Mary approach of writing a transform and hoping it works.  Are all of the schema-aware XSLT packages for C# pay-for-play?  We're using XslCompiledTransform, but it doesn't appear to be schema-aware.

Comment: Microsoft's XslCompiledTransform doesn't even implement XSLT 2.0, let alone schema-awareness. I can't speak for XmlPrime or Exselt, but in the case of Saxon, schema-awareness comes with the Saxon-EE edition, which needs a paid-for license. (It comes for free, however, if you buy an oXygen license.)